# Ruby On Rails won't load @content_for_layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I created a new site with the following code

`rails new new_site`

and I added a site controller and in my `site.rhtml` file

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title><%= @title %></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%= link_to("Home", { :action => "index" }) %> |
        <%= link_to("About Us", { :action => "about" }) %> |
        <%= link_to("Help", { :action => "help" }) %>
        <%= @content_for_layout %>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have 3 files (`about.rhtml`, `help.rhtml`, `index.rhtml`)

Each file has basic code in it for HTML view

Here's the code to `help.rhtml`

```
<h1>Help</h1>
<p>This page will contains instructions and a frequently asked questions.</p>
```

THE ISSUE IS WHEN I CLICK the link for Help. The title changes but the contents don't load.

Comment: I edited your post to use code tags. There is a "code" button on the editor that you could have used (don't use `pre` tags, you don't get syntax highlighting and can't use html). To use it, you highlight text you want to make code and press it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're following a very old tutorial.

I recommend stopping that and reading [the official guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org) (which have a great "[Getting Started](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)" guide), or [a book](http://manning.com/katz).

Comment: Im using RailSpace book. I felt that it was outdated a bit but its still good for learning. right? there are a few changes that I noticed like script/server is now rails server

Comment: well you can install the version of rails that the book uses, and it will make more sense,  trying to use a rails 2.x book with rails 3 will be a lesson in frustration...

Answer (score 2):

are you following an old tutorial?  Try the following..

should be in a file called application.html.erb  in the layouts directory

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%= link_to("Home", { :action => "index" }) %> |
        <%= link_to("About Us", { :action => "about" }) %> |
        <%= link_to("Help", { :action => "help" }) %>
        <%= yield %>
    </body>
</html>
```

or if you just want it for the site controller, use site.html.erb

Comment: Must be a really old tutorial. He's using `.rhtml` files.